# Time for a new tyre?

Tags: tire, safety

On my ride yesterday the rubber on my tyre seemed to rip away revealing the second layer of the tyre. I was wondering whether this would still be safe to ride on. Maybe the tyre is less puncture-resistant in that area but could still be used? [image]

Comment: It can be useful to calculate, estimate, or simply track your mileage over time.  I know my GP4000 tyres lasted around 5000 km each.   If you were to estimate, how far has this tyre travelled ?    Do you skid on the rear much ?

Comment: The shoulders of the tyre look more or less pristine -- did you ride it in a trainer? If yes, the next tyre should be one made for that purpose since it will keep way longer.

Comment: @arne Only used for riding on the road. Can't say I do too much cornering though!

Comment: @Criggie They are probably around 2000km old I'd say. No skidding involved so I don't really know what would have happened with it.

Comment: @MATHBOI I had something similar on a Maxxis Re-Fuse tyre - it barely lasted 1200 km before shedding with basic road riding.  I would not buy Maxxis again, based on that.  What brand/model of tyre was it ?

Comment: @arne I noticed that too.  Do you think, perhaps, it was slightly overinflated?  Vehicle tyres will do that when they are overinflated, but I don't know if road bike tyres will do the same thing.

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate No, road bike tyres have a more or less circular profile when properly inflated and will not deform much when riding, unless you hit a curb or similar straight on. That's how they get away with 20-30mm widths.

Comment: @arne Thanks Arne.  When you write *"profile"*, you also mean *cross-section*, correct?

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate Sorry, yes, that was the word I was looking for.

Comment: @Criggie They are a set of Cadex tyres and in particular they’re long lasting puncture resistant ones. I’m looking at gp5000 s tr as my next set. Cadex rims being hookless makes options limited.

Comment: I was wondering why the fuss for a tyre - I would just change it and be done. Then I checked and saw that they cost about 70€ each...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Normally safe is relative, in this case, its absolute - no, it is not safe. Don't ride on that tire. I would - but only to get home, and I would be feeling for any sign of further degradation (vibration etc). Every road bump would have me ready of a crash in the expectation it was the tire deforming, every corner would be taken as a speed suitable for jumping off the bike if needed.

The traction changes when the tire footprint from rubber to the threads could be enough to instigate a slide. The tire will only disintegrate further with more riding. The threads are what holds the tube in. When those threads get worn though (will happen sooner rather than later), the tube will push its way out the tire and either explode, or worse, ballon and jam between the wheel and frame, lock the wheel and leave you in a messy situation. The tube ballooning when you are cornering will lift the tire and could cause traction loss.

The only thing on your side it is it the rear tire, not the front.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Time for a new tyre then!

Comment: +1. That tyre is very close to sudden, catastrophic failure. No question about it. It’s like asking about riding a frame with a visible crack.

Comment: @Michael but your chances are better with a blowout than a frame failure, especially on the back. I've had a few, without coming off, as well as a couple of near misses from damage to the front tyre causing the tube to bulge out and rub - but not seize.

Comment: I love your vivid description of the feeling of riding with a bad tyre.  Been there.  Finally decided the anxiety wasn't worth it, and hoisted the bike over my shoulder and hoofed it (walked) the 8km back.  I forgot how much I enjoyed walking!

Answer (score 12):

No, this would probably not be "safe" to ride on. That "white stuff" looks like the casing threads(the T in TPI when you buy tires) that gives the tire its structural strength. You can even see the grooves where they used to lie diagonally in the rubber in the upper part of the damaged area.

Could you keep riding it, maybe, but I would not. There is no way to tell when it will suddenly cave in to the tire pressure, so I would not classify that as "safe".

Here you can see a tire with similar wear/damage, you only lack that elegant hole which will come soon enough if you keep riding it.
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:003_Bicycle_tire_worn_through_with_visible_casing_thread_-_mechanical_failure.jpg

Answer (score 9):

I know from personal experience that a tyre like that fairly rapidly leads to a tyre that lets the inner tube reach the road, and that leads to a no air situation in pretty short order.

Mine went from having rubber over the threads of the core to having a hole in the inner tube within a ten mile ride... on good tarmac.

Replace it!

Answer (score 4):

There's another aspect:
Do you want to wait until you get a puncture, even when in the middle of a trip, or do you want to replace it proactively?

When at home you have time and tools, most likely, but when cycling you might not have.

Of course you could cycle uncomfortably "on steel" for a short distance as well (until you are home again)...